Brasero not working on Ubuntu 24.04
Unfortunately, yet more errors after a clean install of 24.04. I'm trying to burn a video DVD using Brasero. If I run it from the command line and create a data disk I see no errors and it burns the disk okay. If I select "Video disk" and then try to add a file the following error is output to the terminal.
** Message: 01:44:33.444: PackageKit: xid = 33554439
** Message: 01:44:33.444: PackageKit: desktop_id = (null)
** Message: 01:44:33.444: PackageKit: Codec nice name: MPEG-1 System Stream demuxer
** Message: 01:44:33.444: PackageKit: field is: mpegversion, type: gint
** Message: 01:44:33.444: PackageKit: field is: systemstream, type: gboolean
** Message: 01:44:33.444: PackageKit: structure: gstreamer1(decoder-video/mpeg)(mpegversion=1)(systemstream=true)()(64bit)
** Message: 01:44:33.446: PackageKit: Did not install codec: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PackageKit was not provided by any .service files
I tried sudo apt-get install packagekit but it says the most up to date version is already installed.
When I tried to do it using 23.10 it said I was missing "Mplex" which I couldn't work out how to install. I was hoping upgrading to 24.04 would fix the issue :-(.
Is packagekit yet another package maintainer like apt, snap, flatpack, etc?
Any suggestions on how to fix - or any other way to create a video DVD on Ubuntu - would be very gratefully received.
Thanks.

Okay - update on 2/6/24.
I used apt to install ubuntu-restricted-extras , which I somehow missed during installation, plus gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad via Synaptic and that moved it on a bit.
Now when I try to burn a disk it crashes with a pop-up error saying Impossible to link plugin pads which is impressively cryptic...
I also tried devede but that just shows an Unable to convert 'N/A' to float error on the command line and hangs mid-way through processing the video file before burning starts.

I don't see a problem in packagekit from the messages you provided, after all it's the tool that is providing the messages that follow it announcing itself.. ie. Message: 01:44:33.444: PackageKit: field is: systemstream, type: gboolean  where PackageKit is telling you "field is: systemstream, type: gboolean"... Sorry I've not written DVD media in awhile (no longer have DVD drive on box) so can't help more

does this set of instructions for 24.04 help?

Alas, the page just tells you how to install it with apt which is what I've done. There's nothing about my issue.
